# How to convert PDF file to DOC file in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web

I am creating pdf file from pdf package in pub.dev, now I want to convert that pdf file to doc file so how to convert pdf to doc in flutter web?

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/docx_template

Use this package if you wish to editthe doc file.

When you save the pdf you must be using

```
await pdf.save();
```

This will return a bytes array add that to the doc file like

```dart
final of = File('generated.docx');
await of.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
```